# Error passing parameters into a servlet

Tags: http, servlets

I want to implement a servlet to get the parameters from the browser and insert into db using http post not http get.

the servlet will recieve params from a url such as this http://localhost:8080/NewServlet?firstname=me&middlename=you&lastName=secret&location=here  , and insert into the db, but Its like I cant do it properly.

here is the piece of code am trying to run

```
  public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,

  HttpServletResponse response)

  throws IOException, ServletException{

  response.setContentType("text/html");

  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

  String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");

  String middleName = request.getParameter("middlename");

  String lastName = request.getParameter("lastname"); 

  String location = request.getParameter("location");

  String result;

  java.sql.Connection connDB = null;

  try {

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {

            connDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + "localhost" + ":" + 5432 + "/" + "mydb", "username", "secret");

            connDB.setAutoCommit(false);

            System.out.println("Connection established : [" + connDB.toString() + "]");

            java.sql.Statement bankStmt = connDB.createStatement();

           java.sql.Statement stt = connDB.createStatement();

            bankStmt.execute("INSERT INTO full_names(firstname, secondname, lastname) VALUES('"+firstName+"', '"+middleName+"', '"+lastName+"' )");

            java.sql.Statement bnk =connDB.createStatement();

            bnk.execute("INSERT INTO employee_details(location) VALUES('"+location+"')");

           }

            connDB.commit();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            try {

                connDB.rollback();

            } catch (SQLException ex1) {

                ex1.printStackTrace();

                Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);


            }
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }




  out.println("<b><font color='blue'>Your FirstName is :</font></b>" 

  + "<b>"+ firstName +"</b>" + "<br>");

  out.println("<b><font color='blue'>Your Middle Name is :</font></b>" 

  + "<b>"+ middleName +"</b>" + "<br>");


  out.println("<b><font color='blue'>Your Last Name is :</font></b>"  

  + "<b>"+ lastName +"</b>");
  }
}
```

When I try to run the code using the url http://localhost:8080/NewServlet?firstname=me&middlename=you&lastName=secret&location=here

I get the following error:

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>
> type Status report
>
> message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>
> description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL*

Well, this is already the whole answer at its own. You're sending a GET request, but your servlet implementation doesn't support it. According to the code you wrote, it only supports POST requests. You don't have a `doGet()` implementation anywhere, but only `doPost()`.

I'm not sure what's the functional requirement is and why this error is unclear to you, but to get your code to run, you should either send a POST request instead, or to rename `doPost` method to `doGet` in your servlet.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your code has other problems as well, among others SQL injection holes, DB resource leaking and mingling the view in the controller. To learn servlets properly, you may want to start at [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Answer (score 1):

You have only defined the do Post() method in your servlet. But when you are accessing using  http://localhost:8080/NewServlet?firstname=me&middlename=you&lastName=secret&location=here , 
the doGet() is called which you have not defined. Just copy and paste the code in the doPost() method inside a doGet() in the same servlet. 
Like this :

```
public void doGet{
 //your code
}
```

Comment: or simply call doPost from doGet instead of code duplication.